# Most suitable verb or noun subdomain to indicate app for .App domain?

Tags: dns, subdomain, naming-conventions

I have a serious problem to find most suitable subdomain for my `.app` domain to describe it's an app.

Let's say I purchased `example.app` which serves a SaaS application with following endpoints:

- `example.app` for a landing page, mainly on marketing purpose
- `api.example.app` for API
- `developers.example.app` for dev docs
- `app.example.app` for webapp -- what?

As you see, the `app.example.app` is obviously redundant, `webapp.example.app` as well.

Using `www.example.app` for a landing page doesn't make me feel like 2018.

It would be great to know what is the most intuitive word to fit in `*.example.app`.

Comment: You could also use `example.app` directly. And I see nothing wrong with `www.example.app`.  Since when is `www` not 2018?

Comment: @PatrickMevzek many SaaS domains omit `www` these days and I just wanted to follow the manner. I'll stick with `example.app` like you suggested.

Comment: This is really subjective. You could use `my.example.app` too, it was popular in the past. Or `home.example.app`. Etc... Trends come and go...

Comment: `my.example.app` is pretty good which sounds like personalized app!